# How do I increase my iterm (tmux) window scrollback (not the line scrollback)

Tags: terminal, tmux, macintosh, scrolling, iterm

When I want to scroll back, i.e. with my mouse (or with <kbd>PageUp</kbd>) I can only go up about 43 pages (about 2000 lines).  Can I increase that?

I have my terminal preference -> "Scrollback Lines" set to 1000000
I also have my bashrc set with

```
HISTSIZE=100000
HISTFILESIZE=200000
```

but these settings aren't helping.

You see how far in the terminal top right, i.e.

[image]

and 1900-2000 seems about the max at which point older content is lost.

Comment: Is that tmux? It has its own scrollback independent of your terminal emulator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Putting this in my `.tmux.conf` file was the trick:

```
set -g history-limit 20000
```

Comment: Ah ha! Yep, `set` is an alias for `set-option`. Here's a related question that I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760281/how-to-increase-scrollback-buffer-size-in-tmux

Comment: yeah.  set-option actually didn't work for me

Comment: Well, the critical bit you added was `-g`. I personally am not sure why that is important, but the linked question might have more information.

Comment: -g means global. That is all values of that setting in all sessions/windows/panes etc. Not just the one where the setting was applied, via, e.g. the keyboard. The regardless. The antithesis of -s (session) -p (pane) and -w (window). This also becomes the new default for a setting if no other per item setting is given.

Answer (score 8):

For tmux you can alter its scrollback buffer with

`set-option history-limit 10000`

The default is 2000.

You can put this directive in your `~/.tmux.conf` or at the tmux command prompt (prefix + <kbd>:</kbd>).

It looks like iTerm is integrated with tmux. See: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/TmuxIntegration

Comment: +1 for a useful lead (looking in the .tmux.conf) though this didn't work as is for me.  My actual answer ended up below

Comment: What was the answer? I don't see any below this one.